# How to move Service into the helmfile?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, helmfile

I have the following `helmfile.yaml`:

```yaml
---
repositories:
  - name: bitnami
    url: https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami

releases:
  - name: clickhouse
    namespace: clickhouse
    chart: bitnami/clickhouse
    version: 5.0.1
    values:
      - values.common.yaml

environments:
  data-ehp:
    values:
  data-prod:
    values:
```

I want to deploy the following service with it `clickhouse-svc.yaml`:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: clickhouse-svc
  annotations:
    networking.gke.io/load-balancer-type: "Internal"
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  selector:
    statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name: clickhouse-shard0-0
  ports:
  - name: http-port
    protocol: TCP
    port: 8123
    targetPort: 8123
  - name: tcp-port
    protocol: TCP
    port: 9000
    targetPort: 9000
  - name: mysql-port
    protocol: TCP
    port: 9004
    targetPort: 9004
  - name: postgresql-port
    protocol: TCP
    port: 9005
    targetPort: 9005
```

How can I add the service into my helmfile ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to update helmfile.yaml as below

```
---
repositories:
  - name: bitnami
    url: https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami

releases:
  - name: clickhouse
    namespace: clickhouse
    chart: bitnami/clickhouse
    version: 5.0.1
    values:
      - values.common.yaml

  - name: clickhouse-svc
    namespace: clickhouse
    chart: path/to/service/chart  # Replace with the actual path to your service chart if it's packaged separately. 
    version: 1.0.0  # Update the version as needed
    values:
      - clickhouse-svc.yaml

environments:
  data-ehp:
    values:
  data-prod:
    values:
```

If you don't have chart, create one using 'helm create custom-clickhouse' 
it will create the chart for you, update the values.yaml with desired ports and oth changes then update your helmfile.yaml to the path of chart